# How to calculate amount of nonanoic acid needed to prepare sodium nonanoate salt

Tags: titration

I have this procedure for making sodium heptanoate, but I need to adapt it to make sodium nonanoate.

The protocol is as following:

1. Dissolve $\ce{NaOH}$ in pure ethanol
2. After all $\ce{NaOH}$ has dissolved, add acid
3. Precipitates will form, dry the mixture in the oven
4. Dilute the salt to a working solution

Here is the chemical equation I wrote: (please correct me if I am wrong)

for sodium heptanoate preparation:
$$\ce{NaOH + C2H5OH -> C2H5ONa + H2O}$$

$$\ce{C7H14O2 + C2H5ONa -> C7H13NaO2 + C2H5OH}$$

for sodium nonanoate preparation:
$$\ce{NaOH + C2H5OH -> C2H5ONa + H2O}$$

$$\ce{C9H18O2 + C2H5ONa -> C9H17NaO2 + C2H5OH}$$

Question:

1. How can I calculate the amount (in ml) of nonanoic acid I need to get 1L of solution?
2. Does the amount of $\ce{NaOH}$ dissolved in absolute ethanol matter? Because I have found related protocol using 40 g $\ce{NaOH}$ and some using 60 g $\ce{NaOH}$

Please help me to understand step by step, since I am not a chemistry student. I am a biology student and I need to prepare the salt for my experiments.

I have included the picture of the protocol for your reference. *I know the answer is 180ml for heptanoic acid preparation, but **how** do I get to the answer? I need to know the calculation steps, so I can calculate the ml of nonanoic acid I need to make sodium nonanoate.

> [image: protocol]

Comment: As a curiosity, why not just follow the second procedure that you have posted and see how much you get. You have broken down the procedure pretty well. If you do not get enough sodium heptanoate for your purposes, do it again.

Comment: Also, the 40 g of sodium hydroxide is to produce a different salt from a different carboxylic acid. The amount of NaOH was chosen to balance the stoichiometric equivalents of acid.

Comment: I wanted to know how to calculate the amount of acid I need because I need to use a different acid for my experiment. 
I need to make sodium nonanoate using the same protocol, but I dont know how to calculate the amount of nonanoate acid i need...

Comment: Okay, then! Edit your question so that is clear. Start with something like, "I have this procedure for making sodium heptanoate, but I need to adapt it to make sodium nonanoate."

Comment: Thank you Ben Norris, I have edited the question. I hope it is clear now so that someone can teach me how to do the calculation.

Comment: According to the first procedure,  approximately 1 mol of  valeric acid  reacts with 1 mol of NaOH. The reactions are quantitative. In the second procedure, 1.5 mol of NaOH reacts with 1.3 mol of hepatanoic acid. i.e they use a little excess of NaOH in the second approach. The key issue here is to know the molar mass and the density of the nonaoic acid to determine the approximate volume you need to add.